# How to create a Winform in Unity and display it?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I am having a released unity game with its Assembly-CSharp.dll already decompeiled by DnSpy.I want to add something that can display information. Due to difficulty to edit UI without the visual editor of Unity, I decided to make a winform by Visual Studio then copy the UI layout code to DnSpy. I know how to add reference, and using those namespaces, then create an instance of Form. But I can't get it displayed by calling Form.show() of the newly created instance.
Can any one help me to solve this?

added on 2021/1/26:
this question was asked long time ago and I didn't know how to ask good answer, as a result I never give any furthur detail such as stack trace or error message. But such info cannot be retrieved any more. Here by informing readers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question.The problem is that the System.Windows.Forms.dll and System.Drawing.dll that I copied to GameDirectory\GameName_Data\Managed is wrong.
I should not copy it from system folder. Instead, it should be the one located at UnityDirectory\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0. Using other dll will cause a lot of errors.